# How to format x-axis tick label in 2^x format?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I modify x-axis label in 2^x format when x is in log2-scale?

When it appears on the graph, x should be preferably in superscript.

Comment: If x already is in the log scale you just need to modify the labels e.g. df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4); 
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(y = y, x = x)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = paste0("2^", 1:4))

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to do it custom transformation and labelling function. It should work on arbitrary data.

```
library(ggplot2)

label_log2 <- function(x) parse(text = paste0('2^', log(x, 2)))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(
        trans = 'log2',
        labels = label_log2)
```

[image]

---

According to alistaire's comment, we can also format axis labels with functions provided by `scales` package:

```
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(
        trans = 'log2',
        labels = trans_format('log2', math_format(2^.x)))
```

Here, `trans_format` will format the labels after specified transformation.

---

According to manual:

> trans
>   Either the name of a transformation object, or the object
>   itself. Built-in transformations include "asn", "atanh", "boxcox",
>   "exp", "identity", "log", "log10", "log1p", "log2", "logit",
>   "probability", "probit", "reciprocal", "reverse" and "sqrt".
>
> A
>   transformation object bundles together a transform, it's inverse, and
>   methods for generating breaks and labels. Transformation objects are
>   defined in the scales package, and are called name_trans, e.g.
>   boxcox_trans. You can create your own transformation with trans_new.

`trans` should be a transformation object (like the return value of a call to `scales::log2_trans`) or the name of built-in transformation, so we can also use `trans = scales::log2_trans()` instead of `trans = 'log2'`.

Comment: Upvoted, but doesn't it seem that having one argument being passed as a function call and another passed as a function name is kind of inconsistent?

Comment: @42-, sure, this looks odd. `labels` can take a function as argument, while `trans` requires  a transformation object  the name of a built-in one. Parsing a function name does not work for `trans`. I have edited the answer to reflect this. And I found it would be better to use `trans = 'log2'`.

Comment: `scales` provides formatter functions too. In this case it's not one of the prewritten ones, but it's not hard to construct with the functions available: `labels = scales::trans_format('log2', scales::math_format(2^.x))`

Comment: @alistaire, thanks for this info. It looks that `scales` has already provided all the necessary functions to manipulate axis scales in order to work with `ggplot2`.  I edited the answer according your suggestion, I hope this looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scales::label_log` with `base = 2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = "log2", 
    labels = label_log(2)
  )
```

[image]